# Elasticsearch multi_match query

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch

I have a search text field in a web GUI for an Elasticsearch index which has two different types of fields that need to be searched on; fulltext (description) and an exact match (id).

Question 1 - How should I add the second exact match query for the id field?  When I search for IDs, the exact ID is within the result "set," but it should be the only result.

The description search seems to be working correctly, just not the ID search.

```
"multi_match": {
    "fields": ["id", "description"],
    "query": query,
    "description": {
        "fuzziness": 1,
        "operator": "and"   
     }                      
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are looking for something like this. Try it.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
     "must": [ {
        "match": {
          "description": {
           "fuzziness": 1,
           "query": "yourfuzzinessdescription"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "term" : {
          "id" : 1
        }
      }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Awesome.  Going to try it.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Dani's query structure is probably what you are looking for but perhaps you also need an alternative to the fuzziness aspect of the query.  Or maybe not - can you please provide an example of an user input for the description field and what you expect that to match that up with?

Looking at [Match Query documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html) and [Elasticsearch Common Options - fuzziness](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.3/common-options.html#fuzziness), that fuzziness is based on Levenshtein Distance.  So, that query corresponds to allowing an edit distance of 1 and will allow minor misspellings and such.  If you keep the `and` operator in the original query, then all terms in the query must get matched.  Given you have a document with a description like "search server based on Lucene", you will not be able to retrieve that with a description query like "lucene based search server".  Using an analyzer with the stop filter and a stemming filter in combination with a match phrase query with a slop would work?  But again, it depends on what you are trying.